# Cannot find architecture name in nested configuration

Tags: vhdl, quartus

I'm building a VGA output block that is using nested elements that provide similar interfaces to build up the picture. The `configuration` then determines the actual screen layout.

So far, I've created one configuration for each block, but I'd really like to use a single, nested configuration. It is allowed in the [BNF](https://tams.informatik.uni-hamburg.de/vhdl/tools/grammar/vhdl93-bnf.html), and I've found [example code](http://vhdl.renerta.com/mobile/source/vhd00020.htm) that uses this, but I cannot get my code to compile.

Inside `work` there are

```
entity everything is
    ...
end entity;

architecture syn of everything is
    ...
begin
    gfx : vga;
end architecture;

component source is
    ...
end component;

entity vga is
    ...
end entity;

architecture syn of vga is
    ...
begin
    src : source;
end architecture;

entity testpattern is
    ...
end entity;

architecture syn of testpattern is
    ...
end entity;
```

Now I'd like to put all of this together using a `configuration`:

```
configuration conf of everything is
    for syn
        for gfx : vga
            use entity work.vga(syn);
            for syn                          -- Error reported here
                for src : source
                    use entity work.testpattern(syn);
                end for;
            end for;
        end for;
    end for;
end configuration;
```

I get an error message from Quartus

```
Error (10392): VHDL Block Specification error at everything.vhd(106): cannot find "syn"
```

The BNF says that an unqualified (architecture) name is expected at this point. What is missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few modifications (additions, and moving your component declaration to an architecture declarative part):

```
entity source is          
end entity;

architecture foo of source is
begin
end architecture;

entity vga is
end entity;

architecture syn of vga is
    component source is
    end component;
begin
    src : source;
end architecture;

entity everything is
end entity;

architecture syn of everything is
    component vga is
    end component;
begin
    gfx : vga;
end architecture;


entity testpattern is
end entity;

architecture syn of testpattern is
begin
end architecture;

configuration conf of everything is
    for syn
        for gfx : vga
            use entity work.vga(syn);
            for syn                          -- Error reported here
                for src : source
                    use entity work.testpattern(syn);
                end for;
            end for;
        end for;
    end for;
end configuration;
```

And your code analyzes, elaborates and simulates (while doing perfectly nothing).

> %% ghdl -a richter.vhdl
>   %% ghdl -e conf
>   %% ghdl -r conf
>   %%

An added entity and architecture for source.
A component declaration for vga.
Move the component declaration for source to architecture syn of vga.
Get rid of all the annoying "..."s.

You'll likely need a configuration for testpattern that uses the configuration conf of everything to get you testbench (if testpattern is a testbench) to elaborate and run. It's a bit premature to show that here.

**Addendum**

After seeing you answer a VHDL question today I took another look at this question and your comment:

> Hm, I have the component definition living in a package, because I need that in multiple places. The largest difference otherwise would be the entity source and the unused architecture for it -- do I always need to define an entity with the same name as a component, even if I'm not going to use it? – Simon Richter Oct 26 '16 at 2:05

I modified the above code with component declarations in a package for `vga` and `source`, deleted the entity and architecture for source:

```
package components_pkg is
    component vga is
    end component;
    component source is
    end component;
end package;

---------------------------------------

use work.components_pkg.all;

entity vga is
end entity;

architecture syn of vga is

begin
    src : source;
end architecture;

---------------------------------------

use work.components_pkg.all;

entity everything is
end entity;

architecture syn of everything is

begin
    gfx : vga;
end architecture;

---------------------------------------

entity testpattern is
end entity;

architecture syn of testpattern is
begin
end architecture;

---------------------------------------

configuration conf of everything is
    for syn
        for gfx : vga
            use entity work.vga(syn);
            for syn                          -- Error reported here
                for src : source
                    use entity work.testpattern(syn);
                end for;
            end for;
        end for;
    end for;
end configuration;
```

This also analyzes, elaborates and runs (while doing nothing).

This demonstrates that component declarations can be used in place of entity declarations visible in resource library work,

Also demonstrates component declarations not used are ignored (made visible by use clause).

That you still received error [ID: 10392](http://quartushelp.altera.com/14.0/mergedProjects/msgs/msgs/evrfx_vhdl_unresolved_block_spec.htm) implies that the architecture `syn`for `testpattern` weren't both analyzed at the type the configuration declaration `conf` was elaborated.

With an emptied working library another VHDL tools gives a similar message if the `syn` architecture is commented out -

> ghdl -e conf
>   /usr/local/bin/ghdl1-llvm: cannot find architecture "syn" of entity "testpattern"

What this boils down to is there wasn't an architecture `syn` found in library work for entity `testpattern` when configuration `conf` was elaborated and elaboration failed.

You could notice the design units are shown above (separated by "----...") in analysis order.

Comment: Hm, I have the `component` definition living in a package, because I need that in multiple places. The largest difference otherwise would be the `entity source` and the unused `architecture` for it -- do I always need to define an `entity` with the same name as a `component`, even if I'm not going to use it?

Comment: Your code example in your question is not an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and doesn't appear to reproduce the problem.  I have no way of extrapolating your context clauses nor guessing what's in the "..."s.  The changes were to allow all the entity/architecture pairs to analyze, after which the configuration declaration worked unchanged. Examine the differences between the abstracted model and your actual design. Component declarations that aren't used are of no consequence (as long as they are syntactically and semantically correct).